# PHP Runkit support on shared hosts

Tags: php, shared-hosting, hosts, runkit

I'm trying to decide whether I should use the runkit php extension for my scripts. The problem is that these scripts should work on the majority of hosts, including shared hosts. I couldn't find any numbers about the amount of hosts that support the runkit extension and even though I suspect it won't work on most shared hosts, I'd like to be certain. So does anyone have experience with runkit on (shared) hosts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will most likely have issues getting runkit support on the majority of hosts.

runkit isn't used by a lot of folks, despite its obvious utility for certain things (in my case, tricky ideas I'd like to support in a framework).

Right now, you basically have to get the latest fixed code off of github and compile the extension yourself, which isnt that hard in linux usually.  This is because the "official" code doesn't support 5.3 features correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've decided not to go with Runkit, because it just doesn't work on many shared hosts and that was required for my project. It really is a shame it doesn't, since it is obviously the best solution for many things.